# API designing: string parser class from OOP point of view

Tags: c++, oop

I have a question that is related to design classes in Object-Oriented programming.  Let's assume I'm writing a message parser class that is used to extracts useful information (duration, frequency and etc) from a string. I'm stuck on deciding in which place should I pass an input message: to constructor or to parse method. There are two variations:

1.

```
class MessageParser
{
public:
    explicit MessageParser(const std::string &message);
    void parse();

    // useful information
    size_t durarion() const;
    size_t frequency() const;
    size_t timeout() const;
    std::string mainData() const;
    std::string auxData() const;
};
```

2. 

```
class MessageParser
{
public:
    MessageParser() = default;
    void parse(const std::string &message);

    // useful information
    size_t durarion() const;
    size_t frequency() const;
    size_t timeout() const;
    std::string mainData() const;
    std::string auxData() const;
};
```

In the first version of class, object can be used only once. Is it ok from clients of this class point of view? What we should do when parse will be called several times? Parse again or just do nothing? The second version of class can be used more that one time. We can call `parse` method with different strings and have different values that can get using `durarion()`, `frequency()` and etc method. From OOP point of view, what's the better choice? What're the pros and cons?

Answer (score 1):

If your parser has a costly and one-off initialization process this is usualy the way to go:

```
class MessageParser
{
//internal stuff
public:
    MessageParser(/*set up parameters here*/);
    Data parse(const std::string& message) const;
};
```

There is no reason for the parser to own the parsed data and allow them access through the object itself, returning the data object will make it more flexible and reusable (easier to make it multithreading safe as well).

But if you don't have any initilazion process to perform, just make the parsing a non-member non-friend function:

```
Data parse(const std::string& message);
```

This old article from Scott Meyers goes in the details of why they are increasing encapsulation https://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197.

OOP is not enforced at the language level like in Java, so you can the overcome some of the limitation.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer the first method and make this object as constant everywhere. The advantage of immutable objects in OOP is starting from simpler use and ending with thread safety (more detailed, for example, [here](https://www.yegor256.com/2014/06/09/objects-should-be-immutable.html)).

The second method I would use, as an optimization, only if I really needed it, for example, due to performance or limited memory size.

Comment: Also I'm thinking that In the first variation of class we can just omit `parse` method and parse string in constructor.